# How to make the tab get focus

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

In my gridComplete function, depending on certain values in the datarow, I want to move the focus to a different tab. The gridCompelete function will be something like

```
           var grid = $('#grdResults');
                var m = grid.getDataIDs();
                for (var i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
                    var rowData = grid.getRowData(m[i]);
                    if (rowData.errorMessage != '') {
                        alert(rowData.errorMessage);
                        $('#UploadMain').focus();
                    }
                }
```

Obviously the .focus() does not seem to work. Given below is the part of the view that has the code for the tabs

```
      <div id="editTabs">
           <ul>
        <li><a href="#UploadMain">Main</a></li>
        <li><a href="#DataValidation">Data Validation</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="UploadMain">
        <fieldset>
          .......
```

What do I need to have the focus moved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for the [select()](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#method-select) method?

```
$("#editTabs").tabs("select", 0);              // Activate first tab.
```

Or:

```
$("#editTabs").tabs("select", "#UploadMain");  // Activate "UploadMain" tab.
```

Comment: Hamidi Thank You..that was exactly what I wanted. Still learning jquery